# Can I find a sorted list of all hands stored as a single file online?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, hand, poker-tools

I'm building a Texas-Hold'em computer program and I need to determine which hand is a winner.

**Can I find a sorted list of all hands stored as a single file online**?

For example:

```
Hand, Rank
AH KH QH JH TH, 1
AD KD QD JD TD, 1
AC KC QC JC TC, 1
AS KS QS JS TS, 1
KH QH JH TH 9H, 2
...
```

In this example text file, all 4 royal flushes have the highest rank 1, then the next 4 best straight flushes will have a rank 2, and so on. If I have this file, writing a function to determine a winner becomes trivial. But I can't find such (or similar) file online.

Comment: you could generate this with code. But at that point, you may as well write out the logic for comparing hand strength yourself instead of making a long file like this.

Comment: shouldn't you be comparing 7 cards, assuming your programs goes to showdown? 5 cards is the flop situation for every user

Comment: @GKozinski I am comparing all choices of 5 cards out of the 7 cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.suffe.cool/poker/7462.html

Contains a list of all 7,462 equivalence classes. If you want all 2+ million distinct hands instead, it would be quicker to write a program to generate them than it would be to download an already made list.

Using that list as a lookup table to evaluate hands wouldn't be very efficient; you'd either have to pre-sort the hand anyway to look up in the 2M list, or else make a list including all re-arrangements, which would be 311M. There are faster methods.

If you just want a blindingly fast poker hand evaluator, there are several available. Kevin's at the same site as above, mine at github.com/lcrocker/ojcardlib (website currently down), 2+2, etc. Mine only requires about 1Mb of lookup tables, and the actual evaluation function is

```
return ldc4[ ldc3[ ldc2[ ldc1[
    52 * (p->cards[0] - 1) + p->cards[1] ]
       + p->cards[2] ] + p->cards[3] ] + p->cards[4] ];
```

Can't get much faster than that (though I'm currently working on a Rust version that might). 2+2's is faster for 7 cards, but their lookup tables are much bigger.

Comment: This is exactly what will work for me, thx

Answer (score 0):

That file would be 311.875.200 rows long. Probably not the most efficient way to solve your problem.

Comment: No, it's Choose 5 out of 52, which is less than 3 million.

Comment: Because the order does not matter, so you can divide 52 * 51 * 50 * 49 * 48 by 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1

Comment: You're correct. But still, is checking a several million row long file the best way to determine a winning hand?

Comment: Maybe not the best but definitely the simplest way. Just read a few MB of data into the RAM once at the start, and you don't need write a tricky function handling all the corner cases.

Comment: @David a lookup has been the most efficient method for at least fifteen years, crushing all other methods.